# log4j2 RollingFile appender

Tags: java, log4j2

I would like to use a `RollingFile` appender, as defined in the library Apache log4j2, to produce a new log file every time the application is launched.

According to the documentation, that you can find [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender):

> **OnStartup Triggering Policy**
>
> The OnStartupTriggeringPolicy policy
>   causes a rollover if the log file is older than the current JVM's
>   start time and the minimum file size is met or exceeded.
>
> **OnStartupTriggeringPolicy Parameters**
>
> **Parameter Name  Type    Description**
>
> minSize long  The minimum size the file must have to roll over. A size
>   of zero will cause a roll over no matter what the file size is. The
>   default value is 1, which will prevent rolling over an empty file.

I defined this configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="fDLL.test.rollingfile" append="False" 
              filename="d:/logs/fdll-test.log" filePattern="d:/logs/fdll-test-%i.log" >

       <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>

      <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0"/>
      </Policies>      
       </RollingFile>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>

  <Logger name="fDLL.test" level="all" additivity="False">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="fDLL.test.rollingfile"/>
    </Logger>

  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If I run the program, I get this error message:

```
2019-02-08 13:00:35,506 ERROR OnStartupTriggeringPolicy contains an invalid element or attribute "minSize"
```

I cannot understand the error message. If I use other values, like `0 MB`, `0MB`, or any other with 0, nothing changes.

In both cases, with or without the attribute `minSize`, I end up with a single file in the log directory, that is `fdll-test.log`.

What am I missing?

---

The main class is this:

```
package fDLL.test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class TestLogging {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestLogging.class.getPackage().getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        logger.warn("warning");
        logger.info("info");
        logger.error("error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have set `append="False"` in your configuration.

According to the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender):

> When true - the default, records will be appended to the end of the
>   file. When set to false, the file will be cleared before new records
>   are written.

This means log4j2 is going to clear the file before writing to it, meaning the size will be zero and no rollover is needed. If you either remove this parameter or set to `true` then a new file is created with each time you start the program.

Comment: Thanks, not it works. I thought I could avoid this issue setting minSize = 0 since, according to the docs, "A size of zero will cause a roll over no matter what the file size is.". I did not think about the 'append' parameter.

Comment: I agree, the documentation doesn't make it clear how these settings interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 <Appender type="RollingFile" name="RollingFile" fileName="demo.log">
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [%C{1}] %message%n"/>
</Appender>
```

Comment: It does not work, depending on what I add I get also some exceptions.

Comment: What exceptions are you getting?

Comment: Dinesh, thank you but I really would like to have a new file for every startup, without any other constraints on size or time.